# How should i use grep in docker-compose healthcheck?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to add healthcheck for my docker app by grep the curl result.
When i run into docker container:

```
curl -sS http://nginx | grep -c works > /dev/null 
echo $?
```

I getting 0 and everything seems fine, but if I'm trying to add it into docker-compose

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  php:
    build: .
    volumes:
     - ./www:/var/www
    healthcheck:
     test: ["CMD", "curl", "-sS", "http://nginx | grep", "-c", "works > /dev/null"]
     interval: 5s
     timeout: 5s
     retries: 5
  nginx:
    image: "nginx:latest"
    ports:
     - "8080:80"
    volumes:
     - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
     - ./www:/var/www
    links:
     - php
```

and check it by `docker-compose ps` it has status "unhealthy". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. You split your arguments in a weird way - `"http://nginx | grep"` and `"works > /dev/null"` don't make much sense and will be passed literally to `curl`
2. You are using a format in `test` which does not call the shell - as such, shell fetures like `|` and `>` won't work since they need to be interpreted by your shell. You need to either pass `test` as a string, or use the `CMD-SHELL` form:

```
   healthcheck:
     test: curl -sS http://nginx | grep -c works > /dev/null
     interval: 5s
     timeout: 5s
     retries: 5
```

Or:

```
    healthcheck:
     test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -sS http://nginx | grep -c works > /dev/null"]
     interval: 5s
     timeout: 5s
     retries: 5
```

For more information on `healthcheck`, you can read about it in the [compose file reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#healthcheck).

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is the pipe operator. Afaik you also dont need the CMD.

You can try it like this.

```yaml
test: curl -sS http://nginx | grep -c works > /dev/null
```

You can also check what your health check is actually doing.

```sh
docker inspect myproject_php_1 --format \
  '{{range .State.Health.Log}}{{.End}} | Exit Code: {{.ExitCode}} | {{.Output}}{{end}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Healthcheck can be specified either in shell form, or as an EXEC array (like you have done).

The exec array doesn't support most shell functionality, like using pipes.

I expect it will work fine if you specify it in shell form. I.e.

```
    healthcheck:
     test: curl -sS http://nginx | grep -c works > /dev/null
```

Or wrap it in `["CMD", "/bin/sh", "-c", "curl -sS ..."]`.